# How to make FreeCAD utilize multiple cores?

Tags: debian, hardware, free-software, cad

I am currently on a modified version of Debian-standard, jessie, using xfce and LightDM with some AMD drivers for the GPU. But my issues are that I am using an 8 core AMD FX 8320, all cores are being detected and are running fine in Linux, but for some reason FreeCAD is only using one (not even entirely) to load a small file. I was thinking maybe if it could utilize multiple cores on my system then it could load the 1.4 MB DAE file without halting the system and taking more than an hour?

Other specs that may be useful?:

- 8GB 1600mhz DDR3 RAM
- A not-so-great ASRock motherboard.
- 1TB HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 07/2019: Partial MP-support was added in the meantime:

> FreeCAD was originally not designed for what you want:
>
> > Multithreading
> >
> > FreeCAD's underlying geometric modeling kernel (which
> >     is a third-party library called Open CASCADE Technology, or OCC for
> >     short) does not support multithreading at this time.
> >     (http://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/index.php?title=FAQ#Multithreading)

Now that part reads ["has partial mulitithreading support at this time"](https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=17501&p=173095&hilit=Multithread#p173095). It has a [Dedicated FAQ-Page](https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Multithreading).

Answer (score 0):

In linux the terminal command

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=<num>
```

will do the trick. FC does a lot more than modelling: gmsh, FEM, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a useless answer. FreeCAD (appimage) launched from the same terminal it's using a single core only.

Answer (score -1):

FreeCAD exports all settings
All the settings of FreeCAD, all in the FreeCAD folder.

C:\Users\a←When installing the operating system, the name entered.\AppData←File Manager ~ “Hidden project” to open, the AppData folder will be displayed.\Roaming\FreeCAD

Back up the FreeCAD folder, when reinstalling, put the FreeCAD folder in its original place.

Note: To clear all settings, just delete the FreeCAD folder, then open the program, a new FreeCAD folder will be created.

FreeCAD exports toolbars and macros I made
Common path
C:\Users\a←When installing the operating system, the name entered.\AppData←File Manager ~ “Hidden project” to open, the AppData folder will be displayed.\Roaming\FreeCAD\Please take the branch path below.

Branch path
\FreeCAD\user.cfg←The “toolbar” I made is placed here.

\FreeCAD\Macro←The “Macro” I made is placed here.

Back up the file and folder, when reinstalling, put the file and folder in its original place.

Record settings with screenshots
In the event that there is no way to export the settings, Record settings with a screenshot, It is the best way.

For example: Desktop location, toolbar location, and more...

Record settings with a screenshot, When reinstalling, It will be restored soon.

The same is true for mobile phones.